# Automatically add rows to repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I got over 15 different folders with their own .pdf files and I would need to automate my process since I got over 400 pdfs.

So my schema goes this way:
First I have flexible content view to add folder name, and then I got repeater field where I add my file name and file.

**Structure looks like this:**
[image: folder structure]

Is there any way to automate this process? Like putting files inside a folder in my server and then run some script to add repeater field rows? So that way I wouldn't have to add everything one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this acf function ([docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/add_row/)). You could read the files within a folder and loop through each file to add a row with the data.

Let's say you have an array $file from the files in your folder:

```
$files = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'file1.pdf',
    'path' => '/var/www/wp/uploads/file1.pdf'
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'file2.pdf',
    'path' => '/var/www/wp/uploads/file2.pdf'
  )
);
```

Something like this:

```
<?php
  foreach( $file as $f ) {

    $data = array(
      'name' => $f['name'],
      'path' => $f['path']
    );

    add_row('files', $data);

  }
?>
```

Would add a row with data (must be matching with your ACF field IDs) "name" and "path" for every file in the $files array.

To get all files within a folder you could use the php `scandir()` function. ([docs](http://php.net/manual/de/function.scandir.php))